# Check if TextBox is created, then assign it's value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a small app, for make my job easier creating definitions (new web forms aspx) via WinForms C#.

Now I have this form, where I tell the app how many textboxes I want to create.

After their creation, I want to assign to a string the textboxes values that I wrote.

```
    private void CreateControls()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < NumberOfRows; index++)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Name = "TextBox" + (index + 1).ToString();
            textBox.Size = new Size(120, 20);
            textBox.Location = new Point(X, Y + 26);

            ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
            comboBox.Name = "ComboBox" + (index + 1).ToString();
            comboBox.Size = new Size(75, 20);
            comboBox.Location = new Point(141, Y + 26);
            comboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DataTypes));

            Y += 26;

            this.Controls.Add(textBox);
            this.Controls.Add(comboBox);
        }
    }
```

Now, I don't know how to check if the textboxes are created, and then take their values.

Could anyone refer me something? Thanks :)!

Comment: You mentioned webforms... but this looks like WinForms code.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes I don't  think `ComboBox` exist in asp.net

Comment: I mentioned WebForms, because I create them with this WinFormApp.

Comment: Please be sure you know the difference between WebForms and WinForms.

Comment: You still are not understanding...
I am creating WebForms using WinFormApp.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to, on `Page_Load`, *find* those controls and grab their values. Since you gave them meaningful names when you created them, this should do the trick:

```
for (int index = 0; index < NumberOfRows; index++)
{
    TextBox textBox = this.FindControl(
        string.Format("TextBox{0}", index)) as TextBox;
    if (textBox == null) { continue; }  // this means it wasn't found

    var text = textBox.Text;
    // work with the text
}
```

However, if the `ComboBox` class you're using isn't a third-party one and it's not an ASP.NET application, the code would work for a Windows Forms application as well with a minor modification:

```
for (int index = 0; index < NumberOfRows; index++)
{
    // you have to use the Find method of the ControlCollection
    TextBox textBox = this.Controls.Find(
        string.Format("TextBox{0}", index)) as TextBox;
    if (textBox == null) { continue; }  // this means it wasn't found

    var text = textBox.Text;
    // work with the text
}
```

I tend to agree with the community that it's probably a Windows Forms application because you can't set the `Location` of a *standard* ASP.NET control. However, if these are user controls, or third-party ones, that support those properties and render the appropriate CSS then we'd never know.

Comment: We have a confusion whether this is winform or asp.net still. have you noticed `ComboBox`, `Location` , `Size`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, yes I noticed the issue, however a minor modification of my code is just as usable on a Windows Forms application as well and you'll see my edit addressing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Page.FindControl("IDofControl") != null)
   //exists
else
   //does no exists
```